# How do I filter an array of objects based on several possible values in angular/javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code:

```
$scope.a = true;
$scope.b = true;
$scope.c = true;

$scope.myData = [{att: 'a'},{att: 'b'},{att:'c'}  ]
```

What is the best way to filter out all objects that match the criteria above?

For example, right now I want all objects.
However if `$scope.a = false`, I want to output only the 2nd and 3rd objects.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on what follows:

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .value('data', [{att: 'a'},{att: 'b'},{att:'c'}])
  .run(function($rootScope, data) {
  
    $rootScope.a = true;
    $rootScope.b = true;
    $rootScope.c = true;
    $rootScope.myData = data;
    
    $rootScope.update = function(value) {
      $rootScope[value] = !$rootScope[value];
      
      $rootScope.myData = data.filter((item) => $rootScope[item.att]);
    }
  })
```

```css
.in {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  
  <button ng-class="{'in' : a}" ng-click="update('a')">a</button>
  <button ng-class="{'in' : b}" ng-click="update('b')">b</button>
  <button ng-class="{'in' : c}" ng-click="update('c')">c</button>

  
  <article ng-bind="myData | json"></article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the javascript array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function like below

```
$scope.a = true;
$scope.b = false;
$scope.c = true;

$scope.myData = [{
    att: 'a'
}, {
    att: 'b'
}, {
    att: 'c'
}];


var res = $scope.myData.filter(function(obj) {
    if ($scope[obj.att]) return obj;
});

console.log(res);
```